# how do i add table content page in pdf file dynamically using html-pdf in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using html-pdf library to convert html to pdf in nodejs. But I have problem with table of contents, for example: like a book index page that show this content from-to this page number like
venues page 1-10
Orlando Scorpions page 11-19
Orlando Scorpions Schedule page 20

Comment: can u plz give more detail, are you want to create a simple table just like an index of any book?

Comment: You say you're having a problem, but what is it? Are you just asking for code?